# Natural deduction proof of $p \rightarrow q \vdash \lnot(p \land \lnot q)$

Tags: natural-deduction

So yeah, the entire question is pretty much in the title. 
$$p \rightarrow q \vdash \lnot(p \land \lnot q)$$

I've been able to derive the reverse, but I don't how to logically go from the premise to the conclusion using natural deduction only. I can see that the two formulas are equal using transformations.

These are the rules I'm allowed to use:
[image]

Please help me understand how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1.$ $p \rightarrow q  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  $       -- (Premise)

$2.$ $p \wedge \neg q \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $   -- (*Assume* the contrary to what has to be proved in the conclusion)

$3.$ $p \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ -- ($\wedge E$ on $2.$)

$4.$ $\neg q \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ -- ($\wedge E$ on $2.$)

$5.$ $q \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  $ -- (Modus ponens on $1.$ and $3.$)

$6.$ $\bot \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ -- (bot introduction due to contradiction on $4.$ and $5.$)

$7.$ $\neg(p \wedge \neg q) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  $   --(*assumption* wrong due to arrival of contradiction)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I knew I need to show $p \land \lnot q$ is false based on steps 3, 4 and 5, but I just couldn't think of the process.